# Invoke in a static method?

Tags: c#, winforms, static-methods, invoke, system.reflection

I have the following code inside a `public` method, however how would I use it in a static method? `o` is a `static TextBox`?

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    o.Text = str + Environment.NewLine;
});
```

I have read up on the [MethodInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the `System.Reflection` namespace, but nothing seems to be working. Just to show you, I want something that does this:

```
public static void writeOut(string str)
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        o.Text = str + Environment.NewLine; // runs on UI thread
    });
}
```

That code does not work, but I want to know how to do something that can call in `invoke` in a static method, like the snippet above.

Comment: "`o` is a `static TextBox`", so yes.

Comment: why is `o` a static `static TextBox`?

Comment: A bit of context, I want to change the contents of a text box from a different thread, and I want to do that from a static method. So I do `private static TextBox o`, and then in the constructor I do `o = output`. Output is the text box `o` points to. -- http://imgur.com/a/GtryL

Comment: That's a really bad idea

Comment: What would be a better way?

Comment: you could supply a delegate to the `Window` object that will update the textbox for you in a thread-safe manner. or, and I very much recommend this route, use data-binding.

Comment: How do I add a data binding, like this? `output.DataBindings.Add(Text);` (I have never used data-binding before, and as usual, MSDN was no help)

Comment: I strongly recommend you take a look at the `MVVM` pattern for Windows desktop development. It's a steep learning curve, but well worth it.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ptmujeeb/wpf-mvvm-pattern-a-simple-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/

Comment: Is this for WPF or WinForms?

Comment: `MVVM` is designed for WPF

Comment: Ahhh well I'm using WinForms, is it still worth learning?

Comment: Thanks for recommending data-bindings. I have successfully accomplished changing the text with this: `Settings.Default.outText += str + Environment.NewLine;`. `output.Text` is bound to `outText`.

Comment: I converted all my WinForm projects to WPF, and I'm glad I did. I have to warn you though, it's very tempting to just copy-pasta right into WPF from WinForms. That is a terrible idea. XAML is a powerful language, if you take the time to study and carefully plan out the implementation. In WinForms, you pretty much just slug out the code. The goal is typically just to get it "working", and move on. In `WPF`, particularly with `MVVM`, the idea is to build a code-base that you can use across many different projects, so it WILL require planning.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Another good demo-article on WPF, if you ever wanna try it out.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818499.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use the `o.Invoke()` method:

```
public static void writeOut(string str)
{
    o.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        o.Text = str + Environment.NewLine; // runs on UI thread
    });
}
```

I.e. assuming that `o` is a valid identifier in this context, and assuming it does in fact refer to a `TextBox` object, then you can just call that `TextBox` object's `Invoke()` method.

That said, I agree with the comments that point out that having a `static` reference to a control instance in your form is a *really* bad idea. It's a hack that means you can only ever have one instance of your form, and it means it relies on correctly initializing the `static` field in an instance method (e.g. the constructor).

If you must have a `static` reference at all, make it to the form object itself. Even better, pass the form object reference to whatever object needs to deal with it. There's not enough context in your question for me to suggest what exactly that would look like, but the basic idea is to only make things `static` for things that are truly static, i.e. not related at all to a type that could be instantiated more than once.

As far as the suggestions to learn WPF go…

WPF is definitely a step up and worth learning but it's a much steeper curve than is Winforms. Winforms has a straightforward control object and event-driven model, with some minimal data binding features thrown in. WPF relies heavily on strong "separation of concerns" programming methodologies, data binding, and the use of an entirely different language to define the UI itself (i.e. XAML). These methodologies are very useful and when implemented correctly will lead to much better, more maintainable code. But it's a lot more work to learn to use them, and the WPF API itself is very complicated, and in many areas without a clear single choice for how to implement something.